# How can I install Team Foundation Server 2010 without a DVD?

Tags: azure, tfs

I have a client who has TFS 2010 and I need to setup my own installation on an Azure VM in order to do some testing, and help them migrate off of TFS 2010 to TFS 2015. However, I cant for the life of me seem to locate a setup .exe online for Team Foundation Server 2010. Is this still possible? Do I need a physical DVD?
The instructions here
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24337
ask to use the physical DVD, but I dont have one. 
According to this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/56343ed9-6c0c-4c17-89d1-62b4bb3cf645/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-2010-setup-downloadable-link?forum=tfsbuild
Its available for MSDN subscribers, but I dont see any TFS versions below 2015 on MSDN download page.

I have found the service pack 1 install, but not the setup for the full product. can anyone help me locate a setup exe online so that I can get this running? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your client can't provide you with an ISO image?

Comment: @DanielMann, not at the moment. There are too many corporate frictions in order to obtain it, as usual with most things

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are installing TFS 2010 to simulate some existing environment and test configuration changes. However, there is not any `setup.exe`   for TFS 2010 in official site for now.

It's unsupported and 8 years old. There have been five major releases since then.  We encourage users move to newly version of TFS server. Either back up the TFS2010 database and do the move directly or use some other machine with DVD to install the TFS2010 ISO image for a test.

Comment: I understand its 8 years old. Logically, thats easy to see. The purpose of me doing the test is to HELP move them off of it. But thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @joey Besides, just a remind, if you want to directly upgrade to TFS 2015, the minimum requirement of TFS version is **TFS 2010 SP1**.   Also add some related tutorials which could help you do the upgrade process.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32183312/in-place-migration-from-tfs-2010-to-tfs-2015 & http://www.eidias.com/blog/2016/4/18/tfs-2015-upgrade-from-tfs-2010-on-new-hardware